# No Activity found to handle intent error using mailto link in flutter

Tags: flutter, mailto, url-launcher

I'm using documentation from url_launcher page: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#android

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<queries>
  <!-- other intents ... -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

code:

```dart
final Uri emailLaunchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: 'smith@example.com',
);

launch(emailLaunchUri.toString());
```

and getting the next error:

```sh
E/flutter (11956): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent { mailto:smith@example.com }, null, null)
E/flutter (11956): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (11956): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter (11956): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11956): #2      launch (package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart:99:23)
E/flutter (11956): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11956): #3      MoreTab.build.<anonymous closure> (package:app/screens/fixtures_screen/more_tab/more_tab.dart:34:13)
E/flutter (11956): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be caused by two issues:

First you need to add this `intent` to your AndroidManifest.xml or add the `queries` element if it doesnt exist yet, like explained in the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). Add `queries` as a child of the `manifest` element.

```
<manifest>
    ...other stuff
    <queries>    
        ... other intents
        <!-- If your app sends emails -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

---

If this doesnt fix it, the issue might be your emulator.

I had this exact issue as well or that `canLaunch()` returned only false while I was testing the app on an emulator. The issue on an emulator could be that **no mail app is installed**, therefor the mail url can not be launched.

So try it out on a real device, it should work fine there.

Comment: The problem was indeed in the emulator, thanks!